# How do I click a button only when the web element is present?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I need to code my script such that it only clicks onto the web element when it is available/present as it may not be on the web portal every time. I wish to click it if it exists and do nothing if it does not.

I have only managed to code out such that the script will click the web element. However, when the web element is not present, the script will meet an error and stop running.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("smb_server").click()
alert=driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

I need to code a way such that it will only click the web element when it is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will not throw any error if the element is not present also, try the below code:

```
elements  = driver.find_elements_by_id('smb_server')
if len(elements) > 0:
    elements[0].click()
    alert=driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
else:
    print('Do nothing...')
```

If the element is present then we will get length as greater than zero, so we will click otherwise we will do nothing. Or you can do like below:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("smb_server").click()
    alert=driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
except:
    print("Do Nothing")
```

Comment: Just to mention that there is no reason to get multiple elements with the same id. Indeed, [the id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp).

Comment: if the element is not present in the page and if you do `driver.find_element_by_id()` then the script will definitely fail, so used that approach

Comment: You are right. I guess that the best approach is then to catch errors.

Comment: don't use bare excepts

Comment: Sure @Corey Goldberg, thanks for pointing out. Is there any link or something so that I can get to know why to not use bare exceptions?

Comment: @keepAlive Just because an ID is *supposed* to be unique on the page doesn't mean that it is...

Comment: @JeffC Noooo. really?? Thank you soo much for pointing that out ;) ... No but HTML specs are specs. What appears innocuous today may not be so tomorrow. When more "legal"/stable possibilities exist, let's use these. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

What about simply checking for its presence? Doing

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def find_element_if_present(id):
    try:
        return driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None

element = find_element_if_present(id="smb_server")
if element is not None:
    element.click()
    alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
else:
    #...
```

---

But given that the element may take time before being fully rendered, you may want to [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) a little.  See

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(
    driver, timeout=3, poll_frequency=.5
).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "smb_server"))
#or EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "smb_server"))
)
```

Many other `expected_conditions` exist, such as

```
title_is
title_contains
presence_of_element_located
visibility_of_element_located
visibility_of
presence_of_all_elements_located
text_to_be_present_in_element
text_to_be_present_in_element_value
frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it
invisibility_of_element_located
element_to_be_clickable
staleness_of
element_to_be_selected
element_located_to_be_selected
element_selection_state_to_be
element_located_selection_state_to_be
alert_is_present
```

*source: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html*

Comment: Any question @Dan ?

Comment: What I mean by when it is present is that sometimes the website changes and the element does not exist. However, I want the script to work such that it will click the button when it is present but do nothing when it is not present